# Could not determine java version from 9.0.1 intellij (windows)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, version

I have a problem with intellij, I can t build my project I have a problem with gradle I think.
The error message is :  information: Gradle: Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebig]
                        Error: Android Gradle Build Target: Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: could not determine java version from '9.0.1'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JVM4.png)

Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to use Gradle 4.2.1 or later to build using Java 9.  https://blog.gradle.org/java-9-support-update.  Are you doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the version string changed from `1.x` to `9.x.x`
I wasn't able to fix this issue in Intellij by using the Gradle wrapper but you can just specifiy a local Gradle version:
[image]

[image]

Like @Stephen C already mentioned you need at least Gradle 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I caught in the same issue one month before. Choose your local gradle distribution from machine instead of using gradle wrapper.

Look at this link.
[gradle error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vJFa.jpg)
and for installing gradle on your machine checkout this link https://gradle.org/install/. Don't Forget to add gradle/bin directory to your PATH.

Hope this helps.